# Visibility IIF statement rdlcreports

Tags: winforms, reporting, rdlc

I have a report with a textfield "copy" in it. This should be hidden when my dataset field "isPrinted" is false.

So i tried this one under the expression of the hidden option of the textfield property:

```
=IIf(First(Fields!isPrinted.Value , "DataSet1")=false)
```

Obviously im doing something wrong, but I have no idea what. 
Anyone who would be so kind to help me in the right direction here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hidden is expecting a result to return TRUE if you want it hidden.  The IIF() is typically

```
IIF( some condition, return this if true, return this if false ).
```

So, if you want the label HIDDEN, you probably want to remove the IIF().  If the "isPrinted.Value" is a boolean, you MIGHT just be able to do based on something like

```
=First(Fields!isPrinted.Value, "DataSet1")
```

or (! logical NOT) if the reverse

```
=!First(Fields!isPrinted.Value, "DataSet1")
```